# Dynamic href tag React in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// This Javascript <a> tag generates correctly
React.createElement('a', {href:"mailto:"+this.props.email}, this.props.email)
```

However, I'm struggling to recreate it in JSX

```
<a href="mailto: {this.props.email}">{this.props.email}</a>

// => <a href="mailto: {this.props.email}"></a>
```

The href tag thinks the `{this.props.email}` is a string instead of dynamically inputting the value of `{this.props.email}`. Any ideas on where I went amiss?

Comment: This is cool staff..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is returning a string because you are assigning it to a string.

You'll want to set it to a dynamic property, that includes a the string at the beginning of it

`<a href={"mailto:" + this.props.email}>email</a>`

Answer (score 45):

A slightly more ES6 way to do what Patrick is suggesting would be to use a template literal:

`` <a href={`mailto:${this.props.email}`}>email</a> ``

Answer (score 4):

A nicer way to do this in my opinion will be to split it into a function and a JSX attr, something like that:

```html
  <Button
    onClick=sendMail
  >
    Send mail
  </Button>
```

```js
const sendMail = () => {
  const mailto: string =
    "mailto:mail@gmail.com?subject=Test subject&body=Body content";
  window.location.href = mailto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be very easy...try it

```
<a href={`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${text}`}>{email}</a>
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you can explain how this solves the problem and how it differs from answers that are already posted here